# DDEV in WSL2: How do I get `ddev launch` to open a browser on Windows?

Tags: wsl-2, ddev

I'm using DDEV and in my wsl2 installation the `ddev launch` command stopped working this week, apparently because the `xdg-open` command didn't work anymore.

Setting the `$BROWSER` variable to a specific browser didn't work as the standard installation path contains spaces and this breaks in `xdg-open`. Also it would break if I switch browsers or use a different standard browser.

```
/usr/bin/xdg-open: www-browser: not found<br />
/usr/bin/xdg-open: links2: not found<br />
/usr/bin/xdg-open: elinks: not found<br />
/usr/bin/xdg-open: links: not found<br />
/usr/bin/xdg-open: lynks: not found<br />
/usr/bin/xdg-open: w3m: not found<br />
xdg-open: no method available for opening [...]<br />
failed to run launch: no method available for opening [...]
```

Comment: Related issue: https://github.com/drud/ddev/issues/2877

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In WSL2 I added the Browser variable to ~/.bashrc

```
export BROWSER="powershell.exe /C start"
```

This opens the standard browser under windows.
An alternative way would be to use

```
export BROWSER="explorer.exe"
```

but this opens the adress twice in the browser.

Links to other resources:

- https://superuser.com/a/1266038/75275

Answer (score 6):

Another way that might achieve what you're looking for is to install WSL (wsl utilities) using:

```
sudo apt install wslu
```

This will install `wslview` which will handle proper windows interactions via the WSL layer including the correct link opening behaviors with `xdg-open`, etc.

After installing, try rerunning your command.

Comment: this sounds like a great solution, unfortunately it does not work for me. I tried removing and reinstalling wslu. do I need to configure wslview in some way?

Comment: If you want to use wslview to open instead of xdg-open you'll need to symlink or alias the two i.e 

`sudo ln -s /usr/bin/wslview /usr/local/bin/xdg-open`